# TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len() #4

Tags: python

Can anyone help please , here is the erreur code : TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len() #4

```
entropy = (map(lambda x: x.get_entropy(), pe.sections))
res['SectionsMeanEntropy'] = sum(entropy) /  float(len(list(entropy)))
```

Comment: It cannot be reproduced because the map object in your code has been converted to a list through `list`.

Comment: I changed it into : 
`res['SectionsMeanEntropy'] = sum(entropy) / float(len(entropy))`
But I got an other erreur of : 
object of type 'map' has no len()

Comment: This is consistent with the error described in your question, not **another** error. But the code in your problem description will not get this error.

Answer (score 1):

Just convert `entropy` to a list so you can use the `len` function on it

```py
entropy = list(map(lambda x: x.get_entropy(), pe.sections))
res['SectionsMeanEntropy'] = sum(entropy) / float(len(entropy))
```

Comment: `TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()`
Here is the erreur with the `float(len(entropy))`